# HornetQ Core API and JMS

Tags: message-queue, hornetq

I have few questions regarding HornetQ:

1. What are differences between HornetQ core API and the JMS API ?
2. is there any advantage or disadvantage on using one of these ?
3. Is it true to say if I use the core API and then I decide to
       change my Messaging Bus (let's say to ActiveMQ) then I have to
       change all my codes ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. HornetQ Core API is a proprietary API from HornetQ, while the JMS API is a standard API defined by the Java Community Process.
2. There are a few features that are not supported on JMS API, that are available through core-api:

   - It's not possible to have multiple consumers on a single topic subscription (say if you wanted to have multiple consumers to scale it better)
   - It's more generic on how you create the subscription. You just create a queue within an address. Very simple.
   - We have a nice API for asynchronous confirmations. No need to block ever if you use this feature.

The advantage on the JMS is portability. Your code stays the same if you decide to move between providers.

The disadvantage on JMS is that it lacks some features and it's a bit verbose, what's under works on JMS 2 JSR right now.

1. Yes, because as I have said here, Hornetq-core api is a proprietary API, hence it will only work on HornetQ. The same way as some message systems will have a proprietary API.

If you encapsulate your Messaging access you can minimize that a lot though where you could just replace a single class on your system using standard OO techniques.

Comment: Please, don't forget to accept the answer unless you still have more questions :)

Comment: thanks for the answer , after reading it now I have another question , Can we have consumers or message senders in the queue where some are using Core API and some are using JMS ?

Comment: Yes.. that shouldn't be a problem.

BTW: You should accept the answer as the correct.. not vote up.

Comment: I know , I voted it up and I was waiting for you to answer my last question !! thanks anyway

Comment: There's just an issue when mixing core and JMS. Say if you are using TextMessage to produce, then you have to implement the proper reading in core, since TextMessage will add the bytes to a CoreMessage.

that will not be an issue if you always use BytesMessage